# VSTS release for a Single Node Service Fabric app takes a very long time

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I a have single node service fabric test environment setup in Azure. I also have a VSTS release job setup to push my apps out to to Azure.

The release job is set as follow:
Upgrade the Application, 
Upgrade Mode = Monitor
HealthCheckWaitDurationSec/HealthCheckWaitDurationSec = 0.

I stopped the upgrade after about 20 or 30 minutes minutes.

Is there anything else I can do to speed up the upgrade process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 1 node, so there's nowhere the app can be moved to, so the upgrade will fail.

Data loss is not an issue for a test cluster, so you can pass a low value for [UpgradeReplicaSetCheckTimeoutSec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/start-servicefabricapplicationupgrade?view=azureservicefabricps)  to the command to inform the runtime that it can replace the service.

Comment: So I was hoping to keep the stateful data on there (albeit there is the potential for loss), will the stateful data remain if I set the timeout flag above, I don't mind too much if it is lost, but would like it to remain if possible?